# Android- capture highest resolution image on onPreviewFrame callback

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm using PreviewDisplay to create custom camera app, and onPreviewFrame callback to manipulate each frame (in my case, send image to server once in pre-defined number of frames while keep displaying smooth video stream to the user).
The highest resolution returned by getSupportedPreviewSizes is lower than the best resolution of images captured by built in camera application.
Is there any way to get the frames in best resolution as achieved by built in camera application?

Answer (score 0):

Try **[getSupportedVideoSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes())**, also **[getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo())**.

Note that in some cases, the camera may be able to produce higher res frames, and pipe them to the hardware encoder for video recording, but not have bandwidth to push them to **onPreviewFrame()** callback.

Comment: Thanks, but getSupportedVideoSizes() return null, which means that it support the same resolutions as preview size.
However, getSupportedPictureSizes() gives higher resolutions.
I don't understand how can I those resolutions, is it available only by capture images through intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE?

Comment: Oh, for sure the picture sizes may be much more than preview sizes. You can use [Camera.takePicture()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)) and specify exactly what resolution you want to get (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent does not allow such choice).

Comment: I thought of going this way, Camera.takePicture() freeze the preview while I need the stream to be smooth even when the image is taken. Do you know any way to prevent the preview from freezing?

Comment: You can go black instead, or play your own animation, including synthetic replay of few frames before freeze. But I doubt you can make it look natural.